# Piping a API Gateway response to client through Lambda handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, openai-api

I have a REST API using AWS API Gateway. The API is handled by a custom Lambda function. I have a `/prompts` endpoint in my API, for which the Lambda function will call Open AI API, send it the prompt, and stream the result to the user as it is being generated (which can take a few seconds).

I'm able to stream and handle the response from Open AI's API to my Lambda function.

I would now like to re-stream / pipe that response to the client.

My question is how to do that?

Is there a way to simply pipe the stream being received from Open AI API to my client?

My Lambda function is:

```js
try {
    
    const res = await openai.createCompletion({
        ...params,
        stream: true,
    }, { responseType: 'stream' });
    
    res.data.on('data', data => {

        const lines = data.toString().split('\n').filter(line => line.trim() !== '');
        for (const line of lines) {
          const message = line.replace(/^data: /, '');
          if (message === '[DONE]') {
            // store the response to DynamoDB
            storeRecord(content)

            return content
          }
          try {
            const parsed = JSON.parse(message);
            content += parsed.choices[0].text
            // ****** I want to send content to the front-end client... *******
          } catch(error) {
            console.error('Could not JSON parse stream message', message, error);
          }
        }
    });
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response?.status) {
          console.error(error.response.status, error.message);
          error.response.data.on('data', data => {
              const message = data.toString();
              try {
                  const parsed = JSON.parse(message);
                  console.error('An error occurred during OpenAI request: ', parsed);
              } catch(error) {
                  console.error('An error occurred during OpenAI request: ', message);
              }
          });
      } else {
          console.error('An error occurred during OpenAI request', error);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Have you found any way?

Comment: Wow! Looking exactly for the same thing for the same use case, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I changed to NextJS Edge runtime, you can just do a return new Response() and it will stream it back to the client. Looking into how to secure these routes as with Edge you can't use Node runtime, so many of the libs not available.